# I can drill back up from the Xcode build, but I can't drill back down starting from "Macintosh HD"

Tags: xcode4.3, finder, application-loader

I need to upload my app file through Application Loader 2.7. But first I needed to get the apps location. I right-clicked on the app file in Xcode 4.3.2's Products folder and Show in Finder. I kept using the Finder Go > Enclosing Folder process to get back to Macintosh HD. Here is the path I wrote down:

Macintosh HD/Users/Steve/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[appname]-[string of letters]/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesos/

Yet when I started to drill down from Macintosh HD, I could not find /Library once I got to Users/Steve. I double-checked and the path was correct when drilling up.

How do I make the /Library folder appear? I'm a PC guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link that may help: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/04/show-library-directory-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: That solved the issue! The Library shows up in Finder and the App Loader too.